# On two-stage-least-squares regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, instrumental-variables

My professor has just covered the concept of two-stage-least-squares (TSLS) regression today.

In particular, we explored the over-identified case where we have a single endogenous regressor, $X$, with $m$ instruments and $r$ controls. It was explained that, in the first stage, we regress $X$ on the $m$ instruments and $r$ controls to get the ordinary-least-squares estimators of $X$, say, $\hat{X}$. Subsequently, in the second stage, we regress $Y$ on $\hat{X}$ and the $r$ controls to get the TSLS estimators overall.

Now, I noticed that we were regressing on the $r$ controls in both stages of the TSLS regression and I wondered why this was so, since my thoughts are that the effects of the $r$ controls are already captured in $\hat{X}$ by the first stage, so regressing on these $r$ controls again in the second stage would either be redundant or "double-counting the effects of the $r$ controls".

I discussed this with my professor and he seemed stumped by this too; he said that this had not crossed his mind before and he could not come up with a good answer for me. Thus, I am hoping that some of the great minds here can shed some light on this intuitively :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not thought about this, but let me have a crack at it.

The first stage of 2-SLS is an attempt to remove the bias caused by endogeneity. For $ \hat X $ to be a good instrument for $ X $, it must be correlated with $ X $ but not with the error/residuals of the main equation.

As with any other regression, we need to include all the independent variables that explain variations in $ X $ in the first stage. Then, we can obtain a good instrument $ \hat X $ and use it in the second stage. Therefore, we will need to include some instruments $ m $ in the first stage.

These instruments are the variables that affect $ X $ and also have some association with $ Y $ through $ X $.

Along with these instruments, we also include all the control variables (all exogenous variables) in the first stage. **Why? Because they belong to a system of equations and are interrelated. All these variables affect $ Y  $ and $ X $ either directly or indirectly through other variables in the system. This means that they also affect $ X $ either directly or indirectly and we need them in the first stage to get a good instrumental variable $ \hat X $.**

> As put by A. Koutsoyiannis in "Theory of Econometrics":
>
> Every exogenous variable, regardless of the equation in which it
> appears, affects all the endogenous variables of the system either
> directly (if it is present in the equation) or indirectly (by
> influencing other endogenous variables in the equation in which it
> does not appear explicitly).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! I guess you have explained why we need to include the controls in the first stage, but I suppose it still does not really explain why we do also need to include them in the second stage? Hopefully others can chip in too!

Comment: @EthanMark It's for the same reason. If you read the quote carefully, ALL variables are interrelated in a system of equations. The control variables help explain both X and Y, so they have to be included in both. X and Y are different variables. In the first stage, they explain variations in X and their indirect effect on Y through X. In the second stage, they explain the variations in Y (direct).